# Xamarin CollectionViewCell not instantiating from storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewcell

I am collaborating with a designer who styles elements on my Xamarin project storyboard. I have trouble referencing his carefully placed elements in code. All the outlets are created, but in a `UICollectionViewCell` the UILabels etc are not instantiated. Here is code from a simple test app to demonstrate the problem.

The Xamarin generated code-behind:

```
[Register ("CardCell")]
partial class CardCell
{
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    UILabel txtName { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (txtName != null) {
            txtName.Dispose ();
            txtName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt to set the UI properties which causes the crash:

```
public partial class CardCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    public CardCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }


    public void Update(string name)
    {
        txtName.Text = name;  // throws exception here, because textName is null
    }
}
```

The view controller with delegate methods:

```
public partial class TestCollectionController : UICollectionViewController
{
    static NSString cardCellId = new NSString ("cardcell");

    string[] cards = new string[] {"Red", "Green", "White", "Blue", "Pink", "Yellow"};

    public TestCollectionController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(CardCell), cardCellId);

    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return (nint)cards.Length;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CardCell cell = (CardCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (cardCellId, indexPath);

        var card = cards [indexPath.Row];

        cell.Update(card);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

I have tried both the Xamarin iOS Designer and Xcode's Interface Builder, but it does not make a difference. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples of collection views driven by a storyboard are quite scarce, but I found [this one](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/StateRestoration) and teased through it meticulously till I discovered that it did not include the call to register a class for the cell. So, remove this line:

```
CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(CardCell), cardCellId);
```

and suddenly everything works as expected.

I was following [this recipe](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/#Data_Source) and other examples, which all had the call included, which is only needed when you don't use a storyboard.

Comment: I had to add a dummy control to get everything to refresh, then removed it.